# How to show the icon of success message with Sweetalertjs in the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Laravel and Sweetalertjs v2 and I wanted to show a success message at the Controller method:

```
alert("Submitted successfully","submitted");
```

And the alert successfully comes up, but the problem is the success icon does not appear.

And in the [docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), there is no code for writing an alert and showing and icon type.

It just written this code which is Javascript based and cannot be used in the Controller:

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
})
```

So how can I show the icon of alert (success, error, warning, info) at the top of the alert box when using the sweetalert in the Controller method of Laravel?

Comment: If you want to use sweet alert in Laravel controller then use this one https://realrashid.github.io/sweet-alert/

Comment: @DCodeMania I tried `alert()->success('Title','Lorem Lorem Lorem');` but still does not show the TICK sign which appears on success messages!

Comment: what you see then??

Comment: @japose7523 cleare the cache and dump the composer and see

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    @if (session('success'))

        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            timerProgressBar: true,
            didOpen: (toast) => {
                toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
            }
        });

        Toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: '{{ session('success') }}'
        });
    @endif

    @if (session('error'))

        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            timerProgressBar: true,
            didOpen: (toast) => {
                toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
            }
        });

        Toast.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: '{{ session('error') }}'
        });
    @endif
</script>
```

Add this to your master blade and pass a message like this. `return redirect(route('dashboard'))->with("success", "Done Successfully");` from controller.

Note: With this, you can pass only `error` and `success`; if you need any, you can make your own.